# delegate = nil, transfer information between VCs issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I just started to learn obj-c and I have question about delegates. I know that on SOF is a lot of similar threads, but I was looking for and really didn't get my issue (maybe cause I'm beginner). Here's my problem: I want to use my own delegate and transfer an information from SlaveClass to MainClass. In SlaveClass in buttonDidClick: action, I declare delegate which is equal to NIL. Even I don't know where I should start to looking for mistake. Thanks in advance for any type of advice. Here's my code which refer to delegate:

SlaveClass.h

> ```
> @protocol slaveDelegate <NSObject>
>
>  -(void)transferNameDidClick:(NSString *)text;
>
> @end
> // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> @interface SlaveClass : UIViewController
> @property (nonatomic, strong) id <slaveDelegate> myOwnDelegate;
> @end
> ```

SlaveClass.m (here appears NIL)

```
-(void)buttonDidClick:(id)sender
{
    if ([_myOwnDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(transferNameDidClick:)])
    {
        [_myOwnDelegate transferNameDidClick:(_textField.text)];
    }
}
```

MainClass.h

```
@interface MainClass : UIViewController <slaveDelegate>
@end
```

MainClass.m

```
-(void)transferNameDidClick:(NSString *)text
{
    SlaveClass *delegate = [[SlaveClass alloc] init];
    [delegate setMyOwnDelegate:self];
    [_label setText:text];
    NSLog(@"text: %@",text);
}
```

Comment: Also a small tip to you. Don't declare delegate strong. instead of strong use weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your delegate in wrong place. You have to set the delegate before going to slaveClass

**mainClass.m**
Present slave view controller like this

```
SlaveClass *slaveClass = [[SlaveClass alloc] init]
[slaveClass setMyOwnDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:slaveClas animated:YES completion:nil]; 


-(void)transferNameDidClick:(NSString *)text
{
 // This is the method getting called by the slaveClass. So it should know the delegate to call this. 
[_label setText:text];
NSLog(@"text: %@",text);
}
```

Comment: You mean [self presentViewController:slaveClass animated:YES completion:nil] ?

Comment: @Anil I put it before pushing SlaveClass in UIBarButtonItem's action - now it works. I was trying before to paste '[slaveClass setMyOwnDelegate:self];' in ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear (both in Mainclass) and in this case it wasnt work too.. Actually why? Can you explain?

Comment: I will explain.. Inorder to set delegate you need to create an instance of `slaveClass` right? then you set[slaveClass setMyOwnDelegate:self], it will set delegate. In the action method you may again creating another instance of slaveClass. You are not setting delegate for that one. When ever creating a new instance(alloc) you are creating a new view controller. Both are not same..

Comment: Oh right..Now I understand this whole delegate-thing. Thanks for patient and explain :)

Answer (score 0):

Set you delegate out side the Custom delegate method. you are mistakenly setting inside the custom delegate method thats y delegate show nil. use like this.

Main Class .M

```
-(IBAction)nextView
{
    nextView = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
    nextView.myOwnDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:nextView animated:YES completion:nil];


}

-(void)transferNameDidClick:(NSString *)text;
{
    NSLog(@"Value from Slave Delegate %@",text);
}
```

SlaveClass.h

```
@protocol slaveDelegate <NSObject>

 -(void)transferNameDidClick:(NSString *)text;

@end
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@interface SlaveClass : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <slaveDelegate> myOwnDelegate;
@end
```

SlaveClass.m

```
-(void)buttonDidClick:(id)sender
{
    if ([_myOwnDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(transferNameDidClick:)])
    {
        [_myOwnDelegate transferNameDidClick:(_textField.text)];
    }
}
```